# UIScrollView: Activity Indicator while loading image from url

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, android-activity, indicator

I need an Activity indicator spinning in a modal view that has an UIScrollView while
the content of the ScrollView (an image from url) is loading.

Any ideas of how to get this done?

As a plus I need to know how to tell the ScrollView to behave like the Photos Iphone Native App, I mean, load an image, adjust it to fit the screen without loosing aspect ratio.

Thanx!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two steps:

- First, download the image and display the activity indicator
- When done, display the image and remove the activity indicator

The tricky part is it probably won't work if you just use NSData's initWithContentsOfURL: because it is a blocking call. On the Mac you can use NSURLDownload to download content asynchronously, you should check if this is available on the iPhone SDK.

For using a UIScrollView to display an image and fitting it to the screen at first, you should check the ScrollViewSuite sample code. It does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanx for the answer man, I'll try NSURLDownload and the ScrollViewSuite (downloading now =D). 

Thanks man... cheers